# Comparing the one value for a row to the mean of all rows for the same column

Tags: r

I have a large dataset that I would like to design the ability for individuals to select a single person for comparison and then to see how their data compares to the average of all of the other people. I'm trying to find the most efficient way possible and am hoping for some ideas.

I've tried creating two separate dataframes and then using lists to manually add the rows together so that I can graph them in ggplot. The extra manipulation, however also includes mutating the data.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars$car <- rownames(mtcars)

df <- mtcars %>% 
    filter(mtcars$car == 'Datsun 710') %>% 
    group_by(car) %>% 
    summarize(disp = first(disp)) 

df2 <- mtcars %>% 
  summarize(disp = mean(disp))
```

The expected output is as follows

```
group   disp
Datsun 710  108
All cars    230.7219
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the output we got, it can be changed to

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
      summarise(car = "All cars", disp = mean(disp)) %>% 
      bind_rows(df, .)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  car         disp
#   <chr>      <dbl>
#1 Datsun 710  108 
#2 All cars    231.
```

---

It can also be done with `add_row`.  Create the column of row names with `rownames_to_column`, `select` the columns of interest, add the row with `add_row` and `filter` the rows based on the values of 'car'

```
library(tibble)
mtcars %>%
   rownames_to_column('car') %>% 
   select(car, disp) %>% 
   add_row(car = "All cars", disp = mean(.$disp)) %>%
   filter(car %in% c('Datsun 710', 'All cars'))
#         car     disp
#1 Datsun 710 108.0000
#2   All cars 230.7219
```

Comment: This is great!, so it was the Bind Rows that I needed. Is doing it in separate dataframe's the most efficient method?